# Acessing javascript multidimensional array with linear values

Tags: javascript, arrays, eval

How could I **set** a variable that I can read by using `eval('productOptionTree' + '[0][1][0]')`?

(the '[0][1][0]' part comes from another variable)

---

**UPDATE**
it's an ugly question, but I couldn't find another way to do it. the only answer I could find is:

> newVal = 4;
>
> dim = '[0][1][0]';
>
> eval('productOptionTree'+dim+' = ' +newVal);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need eval to read the item. Just do:

```
var x = productOptionTree[product[0]][product[1]][product[2]];
```

As you are free of eval, you can now easily use the same way to set the item:

```
productOptionTree[product[0]][product[1]][product[2]] = 42;
```

Comment: but how would you do that in a variable dimension array?

Comment: @djspark: As they are not multidimensional arrays but only arrays in arrays, you can do it in a loop: var p = productOptionTree; for (var i=0;i<product.length-1;i++) p = p[product[i]]; Now you access the item using p[product[product.length-1]].